# Needing help with chip identification: Hard mode

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification

I'm decently skilled with basic ic identification methods and lot number cross reference identification for the rebadged chips, but I've ran into a chip I just cannot identify. On the same board there are some chips I could only track down via lot number, so I'm sure this one won't be super simple. This product was made in China, possibly with anti-cloning in mind.

My leads so far: It appears to be the only micro controller on the device. It's driving a small oled display, a few gpio for interfacing, either has a few analog pins for current/voltage reading or it has an offboard chip I don't know about. The Logo looks like Gigadevice, but they don't even make a chip in the same package from what I could tell...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That logo definitely is the GigaDevice logo.

The 28-pin package and the label "F130G6" point to the [GD32F130G6U6](http://www.gigadevice.com/product-category/15.html).

Comment: +1. A good referens here http://www.elnec.com/support/ic-logos/?method=logo

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that package on their site. Also, I was misinterpret ing the G as a 6 and the 6 as a 5... Whoops. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: The GD32 line is more or less a clone of the STM32, and a lot of the same tools can be used to debug them.